# minikube how to connect from one pod to another using hostnames?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am running a cluster in default namespace with all the pods in Running state.

I have an issue, I am trying to telnet from one pod to another pod using the pod hostname 'abcd-7988b76669-lgp8l' but I am not able to connect. although it works if I use pods internal ip. Why does the dns is not resolved?

I looked at

```sh
kubectl get po -n kube-system
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6955765f44-5lpfd      1/1     Running   0          12h
coredns-6955765f44-9cvnb      1/1     Running   0          12h
```

Anybody has any idea how to connect from one pod to another using hostname resolution ?

Comment: Have you created a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)?

Comment: yes I did .. service with ClusterIP as None

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  The contents of the `kube-system` namespace aren't interesting, but double-checking that the Service is correctly connected to Pods and knowing the DNS name of the Service you're trying to call (not the individual pod) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all it is worth mentioning that typically you won't connect to individual `Pods` using their domain names.** One good reason for that is their ephemeral nature. Note that typically you don't create plain `Pods` but controller such as [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) which manages your `Pods` and ensures that specific number of `Pods` of a certain kind is constantly up and running. `Pods` may be often deleted and recreated hence you should never rely on their domain names in your applications. Typically you will expose them to another apps e.g. running in other `Pods` via [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). 
**Although using invididual `Pod`'s domain name is not recommended, it is still possible. You can do it just for fun or learning/experimenting purposes.**

As @David already mentioned you would help us much more in providing you a comprehensive answer if you EDIT your question and provide a few important details, showing what you've tried already such as your `Pods` and `Services` definitions in `yaml` format.

Answering literally to your question posted in the title:

> minikube how to connect from one pod to another using hostnames?

You won't be able to connect to a `Pod` using simply its **hostname**. You can e.g. **ping** your backend `Pods` exposed via `ClusterIP Service` by simply pinging the `<service-name>` (provided it is in the same `namespace` as the `Pod` your pinging from).

Keep in mind however that **it doesn't work for `Pods`** - neither **`Pods` names nor their hostnames are resolvable by cluster DNS**.

You should be able to connect to an individual `Pod` using its **fully quallified domain name (FQDN)** provided you have configured everything properly. Just make sure you didn't overlook any of the steps described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods):

**Make sure you've created a simple [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) which may look like this**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-subdomain
spec:
  selector:
    name: busybox
  clusterIP: None
```

**Make sure that your `Pods` definitions didn't lack any important details**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox1
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  hostname: busybox-1
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: busybox:1.28
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    name: busybox
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox2
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  hostname: busybox-2
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: busybox:1.28
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    name: busybox
```

Speaking about important details, **pay special attention that you correctly defined `hostname` and `subdomain` in `Pod` specification and that `labels` used by `Pods` match the labels used by `Service`'s `selector`**.

Once everything is configured properly you will be able to attach to `Pod` **busybox1** and `ping` `Pod` **busybox2** by using its **FQDN** like in the example below:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox1 -- /bin/sh
/ # ping busybox-2.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local
PING busybox-2.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.16.0.109): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.16.0.109: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 10.16.0.109: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from 10.16.0.109: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `some_name.ns.svc.cluster.local` can be proper Service's FQDN but not Pod's.