# Openshift/OCP-> not able to resolve the hostname within same namespace. Service is mapping to the POD name which is not resolvable

Tags: kubernetes, open-closed-principle

I am new to **Kubernetes/OCP** world and deploying my application to OCP namespace and trying to connect to **gemfire** server which is also in same namespace. To access I have created a `ClusterIP` `Service`: `ocp-gemfire`. This service exposes `10334` and `40404` ports and same ports are exposed in the underline container.
What my expectation is when I pass this service it should connect from my application as below:

```
ocp-gemfire/xx.xx.xx.xx(Service IP):10334
ocp-gemfire/xx.xx.xx.xx(Service IP):40404
```

But what's happening is , its mapping to underline `Pod` name rather than IP. I am able to telnet IP or service name from application on both the ports; however this `Pod` name is not resolvable.

I am not sure why its mapping to `Pod` name rather than IP ?

```
2020-08-03 16:55:20 INFO  - AutoConnectionSource discovered new locators [myapp-gemfire-1-9npl6:10334]
2020-08-03 16:55:20 WARN  - Could not connect to: myapp-gemfire-1-9npl6:40404
java.net.UnknownHostException: myapp-gemfire-1-9npl6
```

My service :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ${APPLICATION_NAME}-gemfire
  name: ${APPLICATION_NAME}-gemfire
  namespace: ${PROJECT_NAMESPACE}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: 10334-tcp
      port: 10334
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 10334
    - name: 40404-tcp 
      port: 40404
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 40404
  selector:
    app: ${APPLICATION_NAME}-gemfire
    deploymentconfig: ${APPLICATION_NAME}-gemfire
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods):

> In general a pod has the following DNS resolution:
>
> `pod-ip-address.my-namespace.pod.cluster-domain.example`.
>
> For example, if a pod in the  `default`  namespace has the IP address
> 172.17.0.3, and the domain name for your cluster is  `cluster.local`, then the Pod has a DNS name:
>
> `172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local`.
>
> Any pods created by a Deployment or DaemonSet exposed by a Service
> have the following DNS resolution available:
>
> `pod-ip-address.deployment-name.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`.

So your attempts to resolve `Pod` names via `DNS` are doomed to failure right from the start.

You may want to take a look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365596/minikube-how-to-connect-from-one-pod-to-another-using-hostnames/61373132#61373132) which touches very similar topic.

First of all your application shouldn't refer to your `Pods` names at all. For conectivity with your `Pods` it should use only `Service`. It might be in a short form. `Service` name is totally enough when it is deployed in the same namespace as `Pods` you're connecting to it from, or `FQDN` if it lives in different namespace than your `Pods`.

Maybe I don't quite understand something here...

```
2020-08-03 16:55:20 INFO  - AutoConnectionSource discovered new locators [myapp-gemfire-1-9npl6:10334]
2020-08-03 16:55:20 WARN  - Could not connect to: myapp-gemfire-1-9npl6:40404
java.net.UnknownHostException: myapp-gemfire-1-9npl6
```

but the above error message looks like it's coming from your application. So what actually happens whey you're telneting from another `Pod` to `Service` name, it's FQDN or it's cluster IP ? You should be redirected to one of your `Pods`. Do you get similar message that your `Pod` name cannot be resolved ?

I'm pretty sure that your `Service` maps correctly to your `Pods` as it uses their labels under the hood. So even if the `Pod` is destroyed, another one is created and it's available under completely different IP and name, `Service` takes care about updating the endpoints list so it could always direct your traffic to selected `Pods` (selected by the selector in the `Service` definition, which uses those `Pods` labels).

As it comes to your `Service` definition, it looks correct and it shouldn't map simply to your `Pod` names under no circumstances as it would contradict with the very design of kubernetes itself, right ? If `Pod` names are not resolvable by definition, it would be strange that `Service`, being part of the solution was using `Pod` names which are not resolvable.

Error message which I believe comes from your app is showing something different as if your Pods are advertising to this app by their names and than your app tries to connect to them by resolving this name, which of course cannot be done.

Simple Google search for a phrase `AutoConnectionSource discovered new locators` is enough to figure ot that it's a [process typical to **gemfire**](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/geode/topologies_and_comm/topology_concepts/how_member_discovery_works.html), so nothing directly related with **Kubernetes/Openshift**. So as we can see here:

```
AutoConnectionSource discovered new locators [myapp-gemfire-1-9npl6:10334]
```

for some reason this discovery uses simple `Pod` names and tries to connect to them using `<pod-name>:port` connection string, which of course is impossible.